# Java didn't work my regex, online editors did

Tags: java, regex

Good evening,

I'm having this problem. I have a text file with several blocks of commits gathered form Github. I need to split this file in blocks each of one representing a commit. An example of the file is presented next:

```
commit 7aa32a74edba59f1c295a41e95f5deab0d1753c8
Author: borisperezg

commit b6e0a1749da95238af5be0081074ce123bf507bd
Author: borisperezg 

commit 6d77c0a78b2a4b8386fbaeaaeaf28fcf89ec8b2c
Author: borisperezg
```

However, when I use a regex in an online regex editor (or even a local text editor), it works grouping the blocks of text, but Java didn't. My regex is:

```
^(commit\s+[\w|\d|\n|:|\s]+)+
Another version: ^(commit\\s+[\\w|\\d|\\n|:|\\s]+).*$
Another version: .*^(commit\\s+[\\w|\\d|\\n|:|\\s]+).*$
```

My Java implementation is presented next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String lines = // file reader and the content stored here;

    String pattern = "^(commit\\s+[\\w|\\d|\\n|:|\\s]+).*$";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(lines);
    m.matches();
    // Also tested m.find()

    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));     

}
```

I dont know, it should be straightforward.

Please, can somebody help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm curious whether wrapping the regex in single quotes rather than double quotes would help. Otherwise I think you would need to put a \ before the last double quote

Comment: Java class does not have errors. The code compiled perfect. Problem is I dont get any group.

Comment: I also had used ```while(m.find()){     system.out.println(m.group(1)) /// Or 0, or 2...```

Comment: BTW, if a use this regex: ```String pattern = "(commit\\s+[\\w|\\d|\\n|:|\\s]+)";```it takes me the second and third commits. I dont know why it is avoiding the first commit.

Comment: `lines` suggest there are multiple lines. You are also using anchors. The regex checker you are using may already have multi-line enabled. This could be why the results differ. Try using a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String,%20int)) object with [`MULTILINE` mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get each commit separately, you need to use a `find()` loop, and your pattern must end when reaching the next `commit` line.

```
String lines = "commit 7aa32a74edba59f1c295a41e95f5deab0d1753c8\r\n" + 
               "Author: borisperezg\r\n" + 
               "\r\n" + 
               "commit b6e0a1749da95238af5be0081074ce123bf507bd\r\n" + 
               "Author: borisperezg \r\n" + 
               "\r\n" + 
               "commit 6d77c0a78b2a4b8386fbaeaaeaf28fcf89ec8b2c\r\n" + 
               "Author: borisperezg \r\n";

String pattern = "commit [0-9a-f]+\\R(?:(?!\\Rcommit ).*\\R)*";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(lines);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group()); // Captured text ends with a line-separator
    System.out.println("==================================================");
}
```

*Output*

```
commit 7aa32a74edba59f1c295a41e95f5deab0d1753c8
Author: borisperezg
==================================================
commit b6e0a1749da95238af5be0081074ce123bf507bd
Author: borisperezg 
==================================================
commit 6d77c0a78b2a4b8386fbaeaaeaf28fcf89ec8b2c
Author: borisperezg 
==================================================
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for your cooperation. It worked.